# Is it possible to connect to SQL Server from Paradox?

Tags: sql-server, odbc, paradox

I have a module in Paradox where I have to write some records to a SQL Server database. Can this be done using ODBC? How can it be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Paradox? The last one I had was a 4.0 for MS-DOS...

Anyway I found [this](http://www.thedbcommunity.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=210&Itemid=44), maybe useful.

Comment: As I said, it's a lot of time I don't play with Pdox. Please explain the tools you have to write this module (there are snippets in Microsoft Technet or MSDN, or Delphi)